# How to control the appearance of \cline in a table?

Tags: tables, beamer, cline

Below is a code for an example on polynomial long division. I have used the command `\onslide<>` to control the order in which certain things appear first. The only problem is the `\cline`. The command `\onslide<>` with `\cline` does not work. In the code below the second "\cline{4-10}" appears through the steps of long division but I want it to appear last. How can I possibly control it?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{etex}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{pgffor,calc}

\newlength\boxwidth
\newlength\boxheight


\newenvironment<>{varexampleblock}[2][1.0\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=example text}%
    \usebeamertemplate{block example begin}}
  {\par%
  \usebeamertemplate{block example end}%
    \end{actionenv}}


\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

\title{Polynomial Long Division}
\date{}


\begin{document}

{   
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}

\begin{frame}[shrink = 20]
\frametitle{Polynomial Long Division} \pause

\begin{varexampleblock}[20cm]{Example} 

\vspace{0.25cm}

Divide $3x^3+12x^2+5x+20$ by $(x+4)$

\pause

\textbf{Solution:} \pause


\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    &     &                          &                      &                   & $\onslide<5->{3x^2}$  &     &      &     &      \\ \cline{4-10} 
$x$ & $+$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$4$} & $3x^3$               & $+$               & $12x^2$               & $+$ & $5x$ & $+$ & $20$ \\
    &     & $\onslide<9->{(-)}$      & $\onslide<6->{3x^3}$ & $\onslide<7->{+}$ & $\onslide<8->{12x^2}$ &     &      &     &      \\ \cline{4-10}
    &     &                          &                      &                   &                       &     &      &     &      \\
    &     &                          &                      &                   &                       &     &      &     &      \\ 
    &     &                          &                      &                   &                       &     &      &     &     
\end{tabular}

   

\end{varexampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can format your code example by highlighting it with your mouse, and then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: There is a `polynom` package where this is done in a single line, `\polylongdiv{3x^3+12x^2+5x+20}{x+4}` without these fancy arrows and `\onslide`.

Comment: Besides, your code has a lot of errors in tabular, `\\`` are used instead of `\\\``s.

Comment: The plynom package will display the whole answer, I want the process to be displayed step by step. I just don't know how to control the appearance of the \clines.

Comment: Have you seen `\polylongdiv[stage=2]{3x^3+12x^2+5x+20}{x+4}`?

Comment: @Square Can you make a compilable minimal working example with all the necessary line breaks etc?

Comment: I have edited the above code to make it hopefully easier. What I want, is the horizontal line (the second \cline{4-10} in the code to appear last (not throughout the process)  after the line ( - ) 3x^3 + 12x^2 . I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{etex}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{pgffor,calc}

\newlength\boxwidth
\newlength\boxheight


\newenvironment<>{varexampleblock}[2][1.0\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=example text}%
    \usebeamertemplate{block example begin}}
  {\par%
  \usebeamertemplate{block example end}%
    \end{actionenv}}


\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

\title{Polynomial Long Division}
\date{}


\begin{document}

{   
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}

\begin{frame}[shrink = 20]
\frametitle{Polynomial Long Division} \pause

\begin{varexampleblock}[20cm]{Example} 

\vspace{0.25cm}

Divide $3x^3+12x^2+5x+20$ by $(x+4)$

\pause

\textbf{Solution:} \pause


\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    &     &                          &                      &                   & $\onslide<5->{3x^2}$  &     &      &     &      \\ \cline{4-10} 
$x$ & $+$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$4$} & $3x^3$               & $+$               & $12x^2$               & $+$ & $5x$ & $+$ & $20$ \\
    &     & $\onslide<9->{(-)}$      & $\onslide<6->{3x^3}$ & $\onslide<7->{+}$ & $\onslide<8->{12x^2}$ &     &      &     &     \visible<10->{ \\ \cline{4-10}}
\end{tabular}

   

\end{varexampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This is great :)

Comment: @Square You're welcome!